# How to formate dynamically table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to create column with fixed Width in Table.I will explain my problem.
I want to implement on dynamic table which is under div(create table inside a div having three column having width 10 % 20% 70%).Now my data is coming real time mean regular interval of time after one second .
Now I want to show data on width 70%(real data).and on  10 % 20% I don't want to show any thing till now.

Here I am implementing this .I make one div .On button click I start data regualar interval of time? I need to show this only in 70 % of width.So Firstly I create table on button click with three column.Now i want to insert data on third column.

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/x7ZyB/5/

```
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" id="call"  class="" >call</a>
<div id="realTimeContents" class ="left realtimeContend_h" style="width:97%;"> 
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

visit http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/x7ZyB/5/

I have made a change to your fiddle
try that

```
$(document).on('click', '#call', function(event) {
    var tab= $("<table />");
    var tabRow=$("<tr />");
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var tabcolumn=$("<td width='15%' />");
        if(i==2)
        {
            tabcolumn.addClass("lastcolumn")
            tabcolumn.attr("width","70%");
        }

        tabRow.append(tabcolumn);
    }
         var elem = document.getElementById('realTimeContents');
        tab.append(tabRow);
        $(elem).append(tab);

     setInterval(function(){

         var col = document.getElementsByClassName('lastcolumn');
         $(col).append("hi is test ....");
    col.scrollTop = col.scrollHeight;

  },500);

});
```

Comment: fiddle is same as me ..there is no change ..can you please send updated

Comment: any suggetion of this question

Comment: initially table takes the width according to the data inside the td and later if the width extends the container's width, then a line break appears